# Revert to scale=1

Tags: tikz-pgf

I often write procedures that I call from my main draw procedure.  I would like my procedures be independent of the scale of the tikz picture from which it was called.

In example below I would like procedure `\cir` to draw `8pt` circle regardless of the scale of the tikz picture.  Is there a way to revert back to scale=1?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cir}[1]{%
\draw #1 circle (8pt);}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\cir{(0.5,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the `shift only` option to ensure that the scaling effects are ignored as is produced by `\cirA` (red circle). If you wish to have the scale applied to the position then you can use a `scope` to get you to the *scaled* position and then apply `shift only` to just the circle drawing as is produced by the `\cirB` macro (blue circle):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cirA}[2][]{%
\draw [shift only, #1] #2 circle (8pt);}

\newcommand{\cirB}[2][]{%
\begin{scope}[shift={#2}]
   \draw [shift only, #1] (0,0) circle (8pt);
\end{scope}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\cirA[fill=red]{(0.5,0.5)};
\cirB[fill=blue]{(0.5,0.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```